# Javascript: Create an array where the index is the value of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think my problem isn't that hard but I'm kinda new in javascript... so my question is how to make something like the following (the following doesn't work):

```
var t1 = {
    0 : "lel",
};
var t2 = {
    t1[0] : 1,
};
```

Comment: * the t2 array should look like
    t2["lel"] = 1

Comment: use `[t1[0]]: 1` but this has nothing to do with arrays. See [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Take a look at [associative arrays](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html)

Comment: i like this solution even more, great that it's possible to construct an array like that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `t2[t1[0]] = 1` like this:

```
var t2 = {};
t2[t1[0]] = 1;
```

Demo below:

```js
var t1 = {
  0: "lel",
};
var t2 = {};
t2[t1[0]] = 1;

console.log(t2);
```

Comment: Wow ... feeling kinda dumb for such a easy solution :x but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

With ES, you could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for it.

```js
var t1 = { 0 : "lel" },
    t2 = { [t1[0]]: 1 };

console.log(t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

An array literal in javascript looks like this:

```
var a = [val1, val2, val3];
```

If you want to put a value from one array into another array you can do this:

```
var a1 = [val1, val2, val3];
var a2 = [a1[0], a1[1], a1[2]];
```

If you want to use the value as a key for an object you have to do:

```
var a = [someValue];
var b = {[a[0]]: someOtherValue};
```

Or if you need to support older browsers:

```
var b = {};
b[a[0]] = someotherValue;
```

Keep in mind that there are better ways to take data from one array and put it into another array or into an object look at [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or reduce and similar functions. Or you could look at using a library like lodash, which is great for array and object manipulation.